# slideToggle JQuery right to left push and resize

Tags: jquery

Ive been working on this jsfiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/X5mP3/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#slide').click(function(){
var hidden = $('.hidden');
if (hidden.hasClass('visible')){
hidden.animate({"width":"0%"}, "slow").removeClass('visible');
} else {
hidden.animate({"width":"18%"}, "slow").addClass('visible');
}
});
});
```

the idea is to have a more static left bar. a static width toggle div and a center section that will resize upon the click that reveals the panel.

Any thoughts from anyone on this?

J

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remove `.left { width: 50%; }` that creates the overflow once sidebar appear.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/X5mP3/27/